# How to store two value separately in sharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two alertDialog with `EditText`, each one should save a value to be stored in the `sharedPreferences`. But it seems that instead of storing them separately, it just replace the first input value with the second input value. Here are my codes:

```
public void IPconfig(){

        // some AlertDialog Builder codes

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("FirstText", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                editor.putString("FirstText", etIP.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
    }

    public void MonitoringIPConfig(){

        // some AlertDialog Builder codes

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SecondText", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                editor.putString("SecondText", etIP.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
    }
```

Comment: You're reusing the `AlertDialog.Builder` instance between two methods, which is likely the cause of your problem. Each method should create its own `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `commit()` to have any changes you perform in the Editor actually show up in the SharedPreferences, as the Android Developers Page suggests. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Try the following:

`editor.putString("FirstText", etIP.getText().toString()).commit();`

Comment: Doesn't look like that's the problem, the OP is calling `apply()`

Comment: Noticed that. But recently my code didn't also work even though I had `apply()`. When I changed it to `commit()`, it worked pretty well. I don't even know why.